# SQL сервер выдает ошибку на запрос

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

```
cursore.execute("SELECT id, weight FROM test1.treasure WHERE name_pr=\'%s\'  AND inplace= 'y'  ",call.data)
```

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mmdance''  AND inplace= 'y'' at line 1"

в call.data лежит 'mmdance'

Comment: что то (двойная кавычка после параметра) мне подсказывает, что не надо ставить кавычки около %s, он их сам добавит

Comment: @Кирилл Я не понимаю, почему в одном месте используется экранирование перед апострофами, а в другом - нет.

Comment: однозначно дело в ковычке

Answer (score 0):

Дело в экранировании перед апострофами. Вам нужно из этого \'%s\' сделать это '%s'

Comment: Дело не в экранировании: в Python строка `" \'%s\' "` эквивалентна `" '%s' "` (можете проверить в интерпретаторе выполнив `" \'%s\' " == " '%s' "`).